# Iterating through a HashMap in a For Each style

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to iterate through the 'character' HashMap and grab all of the'Stat' objects using something like a for each loop. For example I want to create a function called 'showStats'. To do this I want to be able to output all the 'stat' objects contained in the 'character' HashMap. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
HashMap<String, GameObject> character = new HashMap<String, GameObject>;
character.put("Health", new Stat("Health",10));
character.put("Accuracy", new Stat("Accuracy",10));
character.put("Strength", new Stat("Strength",10));
character.put("Coins",new Item("Coins","Your Money"));
character.put("Head",new BodyPart("Head"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `values` collection

```
for(GameObject gameObject : character.values()) { 
    if(gameObject instanceof Stat) { }
}
```

Comment: Would I then attempt to typecast the gameObject as follows?
`Stat myStat;
for(GameObject gameObject : character.values())
{
    if(gameObject instanceof Stat)
    {
        myStat = gameObject
        System.out.println(myStat);
    }
}`

Comment: @CodeManiak You'd use `if(gameObject instanceof Stat) { mystat = (Stat)gameObject; }`

Comment: ... But you'd be better off **not** mixing different kinds of GameObjects in your map.  Is there a good reason for your map to contain different _types_ of GameObjects?

Comment: @jahroy I'd say it depends on how he's using the map.  If he only cares about `GameObjects` 99% of the time then I'd prefer to use an `instanceof` iterator like this for the 1% of the time that he only needs the `Stats`, rather than having to maintain a separate `Stat` map.  If instead he needs to get the `Stats` more frequently then a separate `Stat` data structure would be preferable.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  That said, my comment is more intended to steer a beginning programmer in the right direction for the general case.  Once you understand what you're doing, it makes perfect sense to weigh the tradeoffs of the two aproaches.

Comment: I initially had separate arraylists and arrays for all of my different gameobjects such as stats, weapons, armors, quests, items etc. but I decided to make them all HashMaps so that I can use a single "Get" function with a string key to grab every single gameobject that a particular character or item has. Not sure if thats good convention, but it saved a hell of a lot of lines :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `values()` method from `Map` interface for iterating through the values only, or you can also use `entrySet()` method to get iterate each Map entry:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, GameObject> entry : character.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    GameObject gameObject = entry.getValue();
    // do something with key or gameObject here...
}
```

More info on the `Map` interface here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the character names (or whatever your keys are) you can do this:

```
for (String s : characters.keySet()) { 
    GameObject go = characters.get(s);
    if (go instanceof Stat) { 
        System.out.println("Character name: " + s);
        System.out.println("Stats: " + go)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that one could also use `entrySet()` to avoid the `get` calls.

Comment: @PaulBellora - I've never understood the advantage of using `entrySet()`.  If you use a `Map.Entry` you have to use _more_ `get()` calls (for both the key **and** the value).

Comment: The advantage is not doing a lookup of every key in the map - less important for a `HashMap` assuming evenly distributed hashing, but it's a good pattern to stick to when coding to interface. No work vs. some work, basically.

Comment: @PaulBellora - Thanks for the explanation.  Though it does make me wonder if it's still better **not** to use `Map.Entry` if you know you're only going to lookup a very small number of keys.

Comment: Overall I like this syntax quite a bit. I'm learning some good info about hashmaps today thanks!